# How to write unit test for Spring Boot Controller if it required user name which was got from Security Context Holder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-security

I want to write a unit to allow users to change their personal Information. However, I don't know how to include the Security Context Holder mock into Unit Test. Especially, it is required to extract the user name which was used to find the User Information by query commands in User Repository. Thanks so much for your support.

Note:
I have successfully sent this edit Information API by using Postman before but it required you have login first and using Bearer JWT to edit user's information.

Below is my Unit Test:

```
 @Test
    public void whenSendRequestToModifyUserInformation_returnUserWithNewInformation () throws Exception {

        String userName = "thanhnghi";
        InformationRespondDTO informationRespondDTO = mock(InformationRespondDTO.class);
        Information information = mock(Information.class);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        ModifyUserRequestDTO modifyUserRequestDTO =
                ModifyUserRequestDTO.builder()
                        .dateOfBirth(new Date())
                        .firstName("Martin")
                        .lastName("Charlie")
                        .address("12 Washington District")
                        .phoneNumber("0794562342")
                        .email("martinCharlie@gmail.com").build();
        ;
        when(informationService.update(modifyUserRequestDTO)).thenReturn(information);
        when(informationMapper.toDTO(information)).thenReturn(informationRespondDTO);

        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.put("/api/users/information")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(modifyUserRequestDTO))
        )
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print());
    }
}
```

And this is my Service:

```
@Override
    public Information update(ModifyUserRequestDTO modifyUserRequestDTO) {
        String userName = userLocal.getLocalUserName();
        Users users = this.userService.findByUserName(userName);
        Information information = informationMapper.toExistedInformation(modifyUserRequestDTO, users.getInformation());
        return this.informationRepository.save(information);
    }
```

And this is my ModifyRequestDTO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ModifyUserRequestDTO {


    @NotNull(message = "date of birth is required")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z]+", message = "First name cannot be number or special characters")
    @NotNull(message = "First name cannot be null")
    private String firstName;

    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z]+", message = "Last name cannot be number or special characters")
    @NotNull(message = "Last name is required")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Last name must not be empty")
    private String lastName;

    @NotNull(message = "Address is required")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Address must not be empty")
    private String address;

    @Size(min = 10, max = 11, message = "Phone number must has at least 11 characters and no more")
    @NotNull(message = "phone number is required")
    @NotEmpty(message = "phone number must not be empty")
    private String phoneNumber;

//    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}", message = "Invalid Email Address")
    @Email(message = "Invalid Email Address")
    @NotNull(message = "email is required")
    @NotEmpty(message = "email must not be empty")
    private String email;
}
```

Component to handle Security Context Holder to look for userName:

```
@Component
public class UserLocal {
    public String getLocalUserName(){
        String userName = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();

        if(userName == null){
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("You haven't Login !!!");
        }
        return userName;
    }
}
```

And finally UserController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
@CrossOrigin(maxAge = 3600, origins = "*")
public class UserController {

    UserService userService;
    InformationService informationService;
    InformationMapper informationMapper;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService,   InformationService informationService, InformationMapper informationMapper) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.informationService = informationService;
        this.informationMapper = informationMapper;
    }

    @PutMapping ("/information" )
    public InformationRespondDTO modifyInformation(@RequestBody @Valid ModifyUserRequestDTO modifyUserRequestDTO){
        Information information =  this.informationService.update(modifyUserRequestDTO);
        return informationMapper.toDTO(information);
    }
}
```

And this is my error log:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<400>
Expected :200
Actual   :400
```

Answer (score 1):

Several ways to do it such as using `UserRequestPostProcessor` or `@WithMockUser` / `@WithUserDetails` or even a customised `@WithXXXXUser`. Refer to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/mockmvc/authentication.html) for more details.

For example, using `UserRequestPostProcessor` as follows should solve your problem:

```java
  mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
     .put("/api/users/information")
     .with(user("someUserName"))
```